# How to safely convert SQL placeholders in python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlite

Summary / TLDR :

How do I safely (**without** room for sql injections) convert sql placeholders?
like make `SELECT * FROM $1` go from `SELECT * FROM ?` (regex substitution works with pattern `\$\d{1,}` but it has it's very obvious flaws like capturing literal values enclosed with quotes)
vice versa is helpful as well to go from `SELECT * FROM ?` to `SELECT * FROM $1`

What I am trying to do :

I have a slow IO-bound postgres connection which is slow and wanted a caching system, I wanted this cache to accept sql and give the output, so I what I decided is to clone the entire remote database and cast it into a local disk bount `sqlite3` space which acts as an "cache" everytime my application starts up (I anticipated that this'll be faster than redis because having something locally will more often than not be faster)

I am using `asyncpg` to interact with the remote database, and this module accepts `$n` placeholder (where `n` denotes the number of placeholders starting at 1)

and using `sqlite3` which uses `?` as placeholder for values and wanted to use a single query and convert between these two.

As aforementioned, I tried using regex and string templates but they weren't safe enough, is there a way of doing this either built into `asyncpg` or `sqlite3` itself?

Comment: Those aren't placeholders, they're parameters. They're similar to Python function parameters. Calling a function with a specific parameter doesn't change the function's code. Similarly, executing a prepared statement with parameters doesn't change the query. The server creates and executes an execution plan from the query and passes the parameter values to it

Comment: `faster than redis because having something locally will more often than not be faster)` not if the data isn't indexed, or the query is inefficient. `SELECT * From TableName` is the most inefficient query. SQLite uses the same RAM as the application, which means caching data *reduces* the memory available to the application. An array or dictionary would be faster than a `SELECT` without filtering. And then, there's the problem of synchronization - how do you update the cached data when it changes? How do you detect those changes?

Comment: Things like `SELECT * FROM ?` or cannot be made safe though parameterization, and the `?` in this string is not a placeholder. Placeholders that can protect yourself from SQL injection can only go where *literal values* (strings, numbers) would go in an SQL query. They can't replace clauses, sub-expressions, table names, column names, and the fact that you are trying to use them that way reveals a deeper issue with your approach than just parameterization.

Comment: Why not start with a neutral representation, e.g. `['SELECT * FROM ', '']`, then you can either `'?'.join` it or interleave `$n`s as needed?

Comment: " how do you update the cached data when it changes? How do you detect those changes?" I intend to set up functions for `execute` which take query and variadic of arguments, when called will act on both the sqlite3 cache and the asyncpg connection and will keep them in sync. There aren't worries about sync in terms of fetching because we only need to be acting on the sqlite3 cache. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Why not just use `$1` in your SQLite statements and avoid a mess of conversions?  It's valid syntax for a parameter token in SQLite.

Comment: didn't know that was possible (my issue is fixed) could you please post that as answer so I could mark you correct @AnonCoward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [SQLite on parameters](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) mentions two salient points:

> Named parameters are also numbered
>
> ...
>
> A dollar-sign followed by an identifier name also holds a spot for a named parameter with the name $AAAA

In other words, you can use a query like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = $1` from PostgreSQL in SQLite or vice versa.

This isn't to say all possible queries are interchangeable, they certainly aren't, but in this one case, you can limit your queries to use the `$1` style syntax for parameters and pass them along unmodified.